# Determine if a given function is differentiable

Tags: functions, derivatives

> For $a>0$, 
>   $$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
> 2ax^2+a(a-2)x+\frac{a^2}{2} &\text{ if $x<\frac{1}{2}$,}\\
> 0 &\text{ if $x=\frac{1}{2}$,}\\
> \dfrac{1-\sin(\pi x)}{\log(2x^2+\frac{1}{2})}
>  &\text{ if $x>\frac{1}{2}$}.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> 1. Determine for which $a$, $f_a$ is continuous at $x=1/2$.
> 2. Determine for which $a$, $f_a$ is differentiable at $x=1/2$.

**My attempt:**

I calculated that $f_a$ is continous for $a=0 \ \lor \ a=\frac{1}{2}$ (Should be correct).

In order to solve $2.$, I calculated the limit of the difference quotient of both functions, and if I am not mistaken (I checked on Wolfram Alpha), $\nexists a$ for which $f_a$ is differentiable. Am I right?

Comment: One says "differentiate," NOT "derivate."

Comment: Thank you, in fact I wasn't sure about "derivate" (I am Italian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The function is continuous if and only if
$$\lim_{x\to (1/2)^+}f_a(x)=\lim_{x\to (1/2)^+}\frac{1-\sin(\pi x)}{\log(2x^2+\frac{1}{2})}=0=f(1/2)=\lim_{x\to (1/2)^-}f_a(x)=a(a-1/2),$$
that is for $a=0$ or $a=1/2$. The right derivative at $x=1/2$ is
$$\lim_{x\to (1/2)^+}\frac{f_a(x)-f_a(1/2)}{x-1/2}=\lim_{x\to (1/2)^+}\frac{1-\sin(\pi x)}{\log(2x^2+\frac{1}{2})(x-1/2)}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$
As regards the left derivative, for $a=0$,
$$\lim_{x\to (1/2)^-}\frac{f_a(x)-f_a(1/2)}{x-1/2}=\lim_{x\to (1/2)^-}\frac{0}{x-1/2}=0,$$
and, for $a=1/2$,
$$\lim_{x\to (1/2)^-}\frac{f_a(x)-f_a(1/2)}{x-1/2}=\lim_{x\to (1/2)^-}\frac{x^2-3x/4+1/8}{x-1/2}=\frac{1}{4}.$$
Therefore, in both cases, the right derivative is not equal to left derivative and $f$ is not differentiable at $1/2$ for any value of $a$.

P.S. If we replace $\log(2x^2+\frac{1}{2})$ with $\pi^2\log(2x^2+\frac{1}{2})$ then $f_a$ is differentiable for $a=1/2$.

Comment: I did the same thing, but I had to plug in the two values of $a$ in order to solve the limit of the difference quotient. I couldn't solve the limit otherwise. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Yes, you have to check differentiability only for $a=0$ or $a=1/2$. I don't see any alternative approach.